# How do I put more than 1 condition on a set of data?

Tags: r

I've got a set of data, `olympic_height.txt`, where each row corresponds to a person. There are 3 columns that tell you their height, their gender and what sport they play respectively. How do I obtain a subset of the data that only contains people that are male and play basketball for example?

I tried this

```
MBP=read.table(file="olympic_height.txt", header=T)
MBP$sex=="M"
MBP$sport=="Basketball"
t=MBP
boxplot(t)
```

My goal is to have one boxplot of heights of male basketball players and one of heights of male football players. When I try this, I end up with 2 identical boxplots and I'm certain they should be very different. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One of `MBP[sex=="M" & sport=="Basketball", ]` or `MBP[MBP$sex=="M" & MBP$sport=="Basketball", ]` should work.

Comment: Thanks. It works now